# En qué capa incluir tratamiento de DataTables en una aplicación separada en 3 capas

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, aplicación-escritorio, arquitectura-de-software

Tengo una duda. Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio de Windows Forms con la arquitectura de diseño en 3 capas, capa de presentación (UI), capa de negocio (BL) y capa de datos (DL). Estoy un poco verde en este tema, por tanto la duda es la siguiente:

Al pulsar el usuario un botón tengo que añadir a un datatable un registro, y después cuando den al botón de guardar tengo que los registros de ese datatable insertarlos en BBDD.

Por tanto, esta parte de código

```
DataRow drFila = dtParejas.Rows.Add();
drFila["Jugador1"] = jugador1;
drFila["Jugador2"] = jugador2;
```

¿donde lo tengo que incluir? Tiene que ir en el `btnAddToDatatable_Click()` (en la capa UI), y después pasarle el datatable a la capa BL, y en la capa BL hacer un foreach para llamar a la DL (donde se hace el INSERT INTO... por cada registro? ¿O tengo que llamar desde la UI a la BL (pasándole los jugadores) y en la BL es donde tengo que añadir los registros al DataTable (la parte de código anterior)?

Es decir, así?

**CAPA UI (en el `btnAddToDatatable_Click()`)**

```
Aplicacion.BL.clsParejas objParejas = new Aplicacion.BL.clsParejas();
bool exito = objParejas.AddPareja(this.txtJugador1.Text, this.txtJugador2.Text);
```

**CAPA BL**

```
public bool AddPareja(string strJugador1, string strJugador2)
{
      DataRow drFila = dtParejas.Rows.Add();
      drFila["Jugador1"] = jugador1;
      drFila["Jugador2"] = jugador2;

      // MÁS LA LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN DE LA CAPA DL recorriendo el datatable, una llamada a la inserción de datos en BBDD por cada registro
}
```

¿O así?

**CAPA UI (en el `btnAddToDatatable_Click()`)**

```
DataRow drFila = dtParejas.Rows.Add();
drFila["Jugador1"] = jugador1;
drFila["Jugador2"] = jugador2;

// MÁS LA LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN DE LA CAPA BL PA´SANDOLE EL DATATABLE
```

**CAPA BL**

```
public bool AddPareja(DataTable tablajugadores)
{
      // MÁS LA LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN DE LA CAPA DL recorriendo el datatable, una llamada a la inserción de datos en BBDD por cada registro
}
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que existe una sola respuesta a tu pregunta

Todos estos paradigmas de desarrollo, son recomendaciones, no son una regla rígida y no existe algo como una receta de cocina para seguirlas paso a paso.

Idealmente un sistema debería ser lo más desacoplado posible. Esto facilitará la modificación, las pruebas y la legibilidad. Independientemente si son 2 o mil capas.

El ejercicio mental que yo realizado, es pensar siempre si ese trozo de código lo llevo a una aplicación de consola vacía, cuanto más código necesito traer adicional para poder ejecutarlo. Mi opinión, es que mientras menos código adicional necesite, estará más desacoplado.

Tu tienes un `DataTable`, infiero a partir de tu código que lo usas para almacenar los datos de un `DataGridView`, es decir tu datatable vive en la capa de presentación.

Lo que yo veo en tu código es que además de problemas con el paradigma, tienes problemas "sentido lógico" por llamarlo de alguna manera, me explico:

1.- Tienes un DataTable (que es finalmente una colección de objetos), que necesidad hay de enviar toda la colección para agregar un nuevo item ??? En tu comentario señalas que `LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN DE LA CAPA DL recorriendo el datatable, una llamada a la inserción de datos en BBDD por cada registro` Pero si estas insertando un solo registro, para que vas insertar todos los del datatable?? No tiene sentido

2.- Tu insertas primero en el datatable (es decir actualizas la vista) y luego insertas a la base de datos, y que pasa si esto último falla? Te quedas con una vista que no es simétrica a tus datos.

Entonces, la que pienso es mejor solución, es algo así

UI

```
private void btnAddToDatatable_Click(){
  Aplicacion.BL.clsParejas objParejas = new Aplicacion.BL.clsParejas();
  bool exito = objParejas.AddPareja(this.txtJugador1.Text, this.txtJugador2.Text);

  if(!exito) {
    //mensaje de error
    return;
  }

  DataRow drFila = dtParejas.Rows.Add();
  drFila["Jugador1"] = jugador1;
  drFila["Jugador2"] = jugador2;
}
```

BL

```
public bool AddPareja(string strJugador1, string strJugador2)
{
     //alguna lógica de negocio, como si los jugadores están repetidos o no, o  si necesitas datos adiciones para completar el registro, o laguna validación

   // MÁS LA LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN DE LA CAPA
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias! Lo tengo algo más claro.